# PostgreSQL backup in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to run a script with crontab that makes a backup of a PostgreSQL database.

My script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

current_date=`date +%Y-%m-%d`

# Delete old backups
find /home/ubuntu/backups/ * -mtime +1 -delete

# Do a full postgres cluster
pg_dump dbname | gzip > /home/ubuntu/backups/$current_date.gz
```

The owner of the file is root, may I have to change it...

When execute the script using sudo I see:

> pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "easydjango" failed: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the proper credential by setting the -U option for pg_dump.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html

You will need to set the PGPASSWORD environment variable if you do not want to be prompted for a password.

```
export PGPASSWORD=mypass
pg_dump -U myuser ...
```

Comment: I receive the same error message inclusive if I indicate `-U postgres` in the command line

Comment: You receive the same error that role "root" does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL considers the osuser itself as pguser if not specified explicitly. You will need to specify the user property while giving pgdump.

Also, the username which you specify should have enough privilege on the database which you want to take dump of.

I would suggest you to create a PostgreSQL password file as specified in this link https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html and then try the dump.